# Android app crash in the OS layer

Tags: android, crash, segmentation-fault

I frequently get an app crash while the ListView is calling on the Adapter to provide backing data.  Device is a Sony Experia X10 with Android 1.6. 
This is just a Seg fault violation, however I dont know how i can fix it?? I do not have any native components - its a pure java app.

```
I/DEBUG   ( 1955): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1955): Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/X10_1232-9897/SonyEricssonX10i/es209ra:1.6/R1FA016/1268206111:user/rel-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1955): pid: 2226, tid: 2486  >>> com.xxx.yyy <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1955): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):  r0 00000007  r1 2c4a14e8  r2 2c4a14e8  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):  r4 2c4a14e8  r5 00902f10  r6 00000000  r7 34828cac
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):  r8 34828da0  r9 2d3dbe48  10 2d3dbe34  fp 00000001
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):  ip 6fbc30c8  sp 34828c70  lr 6d044889  pc 6d03d806  cpsr 00000030
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #00  pc 0003d806  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #01  pc 001f3362  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #02  pc 00260296  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #03  pc 000da460  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #04  pc 000ec454  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #05  pc 000df0ec  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #06  pc 00187d60  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #07  pc 00187edc  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #08  pc 00187f08  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #09  pc 00258162  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #10  pc 0000e474  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #11  pc 0003e68e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #12  pc 000131d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #13  pc 00017a84  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #14  pc 000174cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #15  pc 0004f6c8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #16  pc 0004f6e6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #17  pc 00044d28  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #18  pc 0000f984  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):          #19  pc 0000f4f8  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c30  2c99510e  /system/framework/core.odex
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c34  2c99510f  /system/framework/core.odex
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c38  00902f10  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c3c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c40  00000007  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c44  2c352fe0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c48  2c352fe0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c4c  00902f10  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c50  00902f10  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c54  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c58  00000007  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c5c  6d044889  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c60  2c4a14e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c64  00902f10  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c68  df002777  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c6c  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955): #00 34828c70  34828cb8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c74  70f537a8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c78  009130e8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c7c  6a3dc5d0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c80  34828cb8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c84  6d03d7f1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c88  6a1f334d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c8c  009130e8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c90  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c94  6a1f3365  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955): #01 34828c98  6a3dc5d0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828c9c  34828cac  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828ca0  ffe16d7d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828ca4  6a260299  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828ca8  2c4a14e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1955):     34828cac  00000000
```

Comment: Lot of libwebcore in the callstack... got a WebView there? Looks v like this crash: http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/android-developers@googlegroups.com/2010-03/msg05481.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have encountered a bug in the firmware, either something specific to this device model, or possible generic to Android itself.

It is impossible to say how to work around it, since you did not supply any code or any indication of where in that code the crash occurs. You will simply need to do more testing, commenting out various bits to find what specific thing it is you are doing that is triggering the firmware bug.

You should consider posting this dump plus whatever descriptive information you can to the [Android public issue tracker](http://b.android.com), as you may be able to get some answers that way.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a bug in the firmware. After the fw upgrade this crash does not occur anymore.